# Feasibility of java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder class

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, java.util.concurrent

`LongAdder` is a cunningly designed atomic counter which is supposed to reduce cache line contention when updating a shared counter. The problem is, it relies on atomic CAS operation to actually update the count (this is a trait it shares with a more generic `LongAccumulator` and friends).

On amd64 platforms (and possibly elsewhere), atomic CAS is much slower than atomic ADD, at least when moderate number of cores is concerned. Therefore, it appears, that simply doing atomic addition on a single shared `VarHandle` is a better idea: the code is simpler, while performance is no worse or even better on a common (circa 8 cores) container.

Is using `LongAdder` of any benefit compared to `VarHandle` mediated atomic add?

For a bit of more context:

1. By default, Java does all atomic operations (even simple arithmetics) as CAS loops (for example: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/64644a10725abb4bea8a947508999be6c67c52ed/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/misc/Unsafe.java#L2468). JIT is then free to upgrade the intrinsics to something better if it feels like doing so.
2. `LongAdder`, being a sharded CAS loop, is definitely faster than any simple CAS loop, even at low contention levels.
3. Yet, it appears that "one CAS shard per CPU" scenario (`LongAdder` default) is somewhat slower than actual hardware atomic addition ("LOCK XADD" instruction) on AMD64 *for any contention level*. It can be made faster by increasing the number of shards substantially (at least 2x CPU count, with additional gains realizable on large multiplies, like 8x and beyond).
4. Still, a simple sharding of a proper atomic counter (the one that does hardware addition instead of CAS) will still be faster and simpler.

Comment: Chances are your benchmark is flawed. Please share it.

Answer (score 0):

`LongAdder` was designed to scale better in write-heavy scenarios as opposed to `AtomicLong`, at any level of contention except none, and indeed it does.

If your scenario is not write-heavy, then `AtomicLong` will be faster.

C2 compiler always replaces `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`-annotated methods with hardcoded assembly, not only when it feels like doing so.

`lock xadd` is faster than CAS retry loop to increment a value. `LongAdder` is faster than `lock xadd`, because it splits the counter between threads. It creates multiple counters, therefore reducing contention.

Comment: There's no doubt than `LongAdder` is faster than a simple CAS loop (as you may be aware, JVM does all atomic ops as CAS by default, and may selectively promote some CAS uses to "LOCK XADD"). However, it appears to me that "LOCK XADD" is always faster on AMD64 than even sharded CAS, no matter the contention level.

Comment: @oakad This is trivial to prove using a JMH benchmark. I observed 535M/s on LongAdder and 47M/s with XADD on an 8-core + 8-thread run.